# Blogger API - Google Scripts Access Token

Tags: api, blogger

I found this code here but I can't figure out where to get this ?

"headers" : { "Authorization" : "Bearer YOUR_ACTIVE_TOKEN"}

I have looked and researched every where but I can't find how to get this "Active Token". Can some one please help me to get this ?

```
        function testBlogger() {

          var payload =
          {
            "kind": "blogger#post",
            "blog": {
              "id": "YOUR_BLOG_ID"
            },
            "title": "New post",
            "content": "With content..."
          };

        var options =
          {
            "method" : "post",
            "headers" : { "Authorization" : "Bearer YOUR_ACTIVE_TOKEN"},
            "contentType" : "application/json",
            "payload" : '{ "kind": "blogger#post", "blog": { "id": "YOUR_BLOG_ID" },      "title": "New post", "content": "With content..." }'
          };

      try {

        var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/YOUR_BLOG_ID/posts",
          options);

        Logger.log(result);

      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e);
      }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It involves a few more steps. You need to include the OAuth2 library in your project, enable the Blogger API in the Google Developers console and also create a new a browser key to get your client ID and secret.

```
     var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "headers" : { "Authorization" : "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken()},
        "contentType" : "application/json",
        "payload" : '{ "kind": "blogger#post", "blog": { "id": "YOUR_BLOG_ID" },      "title": "New post", "content": "With content..." }'
      };
```

See: [Using Blogger API with Google Apps Script](http://ctrlq.org/code/20068-blogger-api-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Hi Amit, I was hoping to contact you through your website. This is where all started from your post as per your link above. I am trying to post to Blogger using Google Scripts. I tried your script but I don't know how to include OAuth2 library. I added using Resources, enable Blogger API but nothing happen. Any help will be much apprecited.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple steps required to initially setup the code environment to access OAuth2 APIs. In summary

1. Add an [OAuth2 client library](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) to your script project
2. Enable the Blogger API in the script project's associated Google Developers Console project
3. Setup a OAuth service in your script project
4. Authenticate access to generate the tokens

My blog post details all these steps https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/10/setting-up-oauth2-access-with-google-apps-script-blogger-api-example/

Comment: If you link to your site or blog or project or product, you need to provide proper disclosure.