# urlfetch data from a page after login using appscript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am trying to extract data from a webpage which requires login.
The following code with

```js
URLfetchapp.fetch(x).getcontentText()
```

returns the login page, however I want to get the data after login security page. Code to get data from the page is :

```js
function getPTtrack(linksArray){
  linksArray = `https://www.blogger.com/about/`;
  var ptTracknames = [];
  for(var sear in linksArray){
       var optoutlink= linksArray[sear].toString().search("Publish your passion");
   if(optoutlink!=-1){
  var x = linksArray[sear].replace(">.","").replace("<","").replace(">","").toString();
  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(x).getContentText(); 
  var number = page.match(/<b>(.*)<\/b>/)[1];
  Logger.log(number);
  ptTracknames.push(number);
  }
  }
  console.log(ptTracknames);
  return ptTracknames;
}
```

But when I run the code to get the data after login to the page. I didn't get the data from next page instead I get the login page html code in console. Can anyone please suggest what code should I use

Comment: On your provided script, specifically on your `for...in` statement, the `linksArray` on the line `for(var sear in linksArray)` isn't an object but a string. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & update your question's code to be actually reproducible.

Comment: blogger.com has its own API that you have to use. Get a token, send requests with the token etc, get response, send another request, etc... See docs here: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using and some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621070/blogger-api-google-scripts-access-token

Comment: https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/10/setting-up-oauth2-access-with-google-apps-script-blogger-api-example/